# NEON increasing run time

Tags: c++, neon

I am currently trying to optimize some of my image processing code to use NEON instructions.

Let's say I have to very large float arrays and I want to multiply each value of the first one with three consecutive values of the second one. (The second one is three times as large.)

```
float*     l_ptrGauss_pf32   = [...];
float*     l_ptrLaplace_pf32 = [...]; // Three times as large 

for (uint64_t k = 0; k < l_numPixels_ui64; ++k)
{
    float l_weight_f32 = *l_ptrGauss_pf32;

    *l_ptrLaplace_pf32 *= l_weight_f32;
    ++l_ptrLaplace_pf32;
    *l_ptrLaplace_pf32 *= l_weight_f32;
    ++l_ptrLaplace_pf32;
    *l_ptrLaplace_pf32 *= l_weight_f32;
    ++l_ptrLaplace_pf32;

    ++l_ptrGauss_pf32;
}
```

So when I replace the above code with NEON intrinsics, the run time is about 10% longer.

```
float32x4_t l_gaussElem_f32x4;
float32x4_t l_laplElem1_f32x4;
float32x4_t l_laplElem2_f32x4;
float32x4_t l_laplElem3_f32x4;

for( uint64_t k=0; k<(l_lastPixelInBlock_ui64/4); ++k)
{
    l_gaussElem_f32x4 = vld1q_f32(l_ptrGauss_pf32);
    l_laplElem1_f32x4 = vld1q_f32(l_ptrLaplace_pf32);
    l_laplElem2_f32x4 = vld1q_f32(l_ptrLaplace_pf32+4);
    l_laplElem3_f32x4 = vld1q_f32(l_ptrLaplace_pf32+8);

    l_laplElem1_f32x4 = vmulq_f32(l_gaussElem_f32x4, l_laplElem1_f32x4);
    l_laplElem2_f32x4 = vmulq_f32(l_gaussElem_f32x4, l_laplElem2_f32x4);
    l_laplElem3_f32x4 = vmulq_f32(l_gaussElem_f32x4, l_laplElem3_f32x4);

    vst1q_f32(l_ptrLaplace_pf32,   l_laplElem1_f32x4);
    vst1q_f32(l_ptrLaplace_pf32+4, l_laplElem2_f32x4);
    vst1q_f32(l_ptrLaplace_pf32+8, l_laplElem3_f32x4);

    l_ptrLaplace_pf32 += 12;
    l_ptrGauss_pf32   += 4;
}
```

Both versions are compiled with -Ofast using Apple LLVM 8.0. Is the compiler really so good at optimizing this code even without NEON intrinsics?

Comment: Did you inspect the code generated by the compiler? Clang does use Neon instructions (assuming you "let it") without you having to resort to intrinsics, and often does a better job than when you do use intrinsics (because it will be more clever about how it arranges the instructions and operations, where intrinsics tend to be looked at as "must be exactly this way").

Comment: It may also be that the unrolling or other re-arranging of the loop becomes different because of your hand-unrolling.

Comment: Is this for armv7 or arm64? Also, minor tangent, but it's probably better to use `size_t` for `k` and `l_lastPixelInBlock_ui64` (since on armv7 is 32-bit). Additionally, can the pointers alias? If not, marking them as `restrict` should help.

Answer (score 0):

You code contains relatively many operations of vector loading and a few operations of multiplication. So I would recommend to optimize loading of vectors. There are two steps:

- Use aligned memory in your arrays.
- Use prefetch.

In order to do this I would recommend to use next function:

```
inline float32x4_t Load(const float * p)
{
    // use prefetch:
    __builtin_prefetch(p + 256); 
    // tell compiler that address is aligned:
    float * _p = (float *)__builtin_assume_aligned(p, 16);
    return vld1q_f32(_p);
}
```